# Android: receive Bluetooth data send with "unicast connectionsless mode"

Tags: android, bluetooth

I wanted to experiment a bit with an old bluetooth device and my smartphone. The device uses the Bluetooth 3.0's unicast connectionless mode to send data. I'd like to read this data with my smartphone, without establishing a connection. Reason? The device has a big range of about 50 meters, the smartphone only about 10 meters. I'd like to receive the data even if I am further away than 10 meters. Is it possible?

I googled on the topic and I found somewhere in the API some mysterious constants definitions "L2CAP" or so, with a comment "Unicast connectionless mode", which means, there seems to be a support for this feature. But except of those constants I found nothing - no functions, classes, methods, examples.

I would be thankful for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `L2CAP` is not supported version 4.2 onwards, there is an open issue on Android website which have more details.

[Issue 58164:   Support Bluetooth L2CAP](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58164)

There seem to be no response on when fix will be done. I am too waiting for fix :-(